# Splitting Solr response time

Tags: solr, response-time

Is it possible to retrieve any other time from Solr besides the Qtime. If not, is it somehow possible to measure the time  not included by QTime, i.e (citing the Solr terminology), the time spent in the response writer formatting/streaming the response to the client. Is there any good resource where I can read about these things? Searching the internet,I found only partial and unclear information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [debugQuery=on](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Debugging) option to check for the response times of individual components.

e.g.

```
<lst name="timing">
<double name="time">9.0</double>
<lst name="prepare">
  <double name="time">1.0</double>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
    <double name="time">1.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
</lst>
<lst name="process">
  <double name="time">8.0</double>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
    <double name="time">6.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
    <double name="time">2.0</double>
  </lst>
</lst>
```

Comment: In my case in the response I get only the QTime although the debugQuery=on. Is there something else I should configure in order to get the same format of response as you yours? Thanks!

Comment: the debug information is present at the very end of the result after the response and facets and not in the header.

Comment: Thanks! Can I somehow return the elapsed time in the response? And where I can read more about the meaning of each of these times?

Comment: try debugQuery=true or debugQuery=on you should get the response as above. Also for explaination you can check the http://explain.solr.pl/explains site.

Comment: Ok, but I was meaning on the elapsed time for writing the response to the client, not only on the time needed to execute the query.How can it be measured?

Comment: the response to client is more on the browser side which you can check with Developer tools or firebug. This is not related to Solr.